# QGIS Grid Shift Files

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

[image]QGIS is freezing on a transformation between EPSG:26912 and EPSG:3402.  It appears to be looking for a grid shift file AB_CSRS.DAC which I can get from the federal government but I don't know how or where to apply it in QGIS.  What am I missing?

Comment: How do you know it's looking for that file? If it gives you an error message, please add the text of the error message to your question.

Comment: Please see attached image.

Comment: @Mikeoramma,  If you have the _AB_CSRS.DAC_ file, put it in your QGIS `\share\proj` folder.

Comment: More likely to get it from the Alberta government.

Comment: No, the federal gov creates and maintains that stuff not the province.  Thanks Gabriel, that was the spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grids are readed from the `\share\proj` foler.
Depending on the operating system and the installation is where it is located.

In Windows machines it is in the `QGIS version` folder for stand-alone default installs, or in the `OSGeo4W folder` for OSGeo4W default installs. In Linux it can be in `/usr` or in `/usr/local`.

If you have already the grid file, just save it in your `\share\proj` folder and PROJ, QGIS and GDAL will read the grid from there.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. I want to add: for me it was still necessary to place it in the QGIS-Folder. This file existed already in the OSGeo4W folder, without resolving the error message.